# Date validation in GWT

Tags: validation, date, gwt, datebox

I want to validate date in my DateBox. There is how I do it:

```
private DateBox addContDateCreateDateBox = new DateBox();
private DateTimeFormat ft_big = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
addContDateCreateDateBox.setFormat(new DateBox.DefaultFormat(ft_big));
addContDateCreateDateBox.setValue(new Date());
Boolean fl = true;
if (addContDateCreateDateBox.getValue() != null) {
  try {                     
   ft_big.parseStrict(addContDateCreateDateBox.getValue().toString());
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
   fl = false;              
  }
} else  fl = false;
```

But even if I put correct date in DateBox I receive fl==false. I don't know why but this addContDateCreateDateBox.getValue().toString() against '02.08.2013' return 
'Fri Aug 02 00:00:00 EEST 2013'.

Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTimeFormat.parseStrict()
```

expects a String and

```
addContDateCreateDateBox.getValue().toString()
```

returns 'Fri Aug 02 00:00:00 EEST 2013' which is not parseable according to the format you specified ("dd.MM.yyyy") in

```
private DateTimeFormat ft_big = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Instead use

```
ft_big.format(addContDateCreateDateBox.getValue());
```

to format the date returned by

```
addContDateCreateDateBox.getValue()
```

After the date is properly formatted you can use the parseStrict() method to enforce the format is respected.